# Como alterar o formato do type=date pra aparecer só mês e ano?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Então pessoal, to quebrando a cabeça aqui. tenho um input do type=date e quero q invés dele mostrar DD/MM/AAAA eu queria que só mostrasse MM/AAAA para o usuário. e também que o ano mínimo seja o atual.

```
<input required="required" type="date" id="date" placeholder="&zwnj;" />
```

eu procurei aqui no fórum e não achei nada que resolva esse problema meu somente em outras linguagens.

OBS: consegui fazer com o 'select' mas não achei legal pq ficou mts linhas de codigo e tive q colocar 1 por 1. e acredito q vai ser dificil de mexer com esses dados no sql.

```
<div>
                    <select name="mes" required>
                        <option value="Janeiro">01</option>
                        <option value="Fevereiro">02</option>
                        <option value="marco">03</option>
                        <option value="abril">04</option>
                        <option value="maio">05</option>
                        <option value="junho">06</option>
                        <option value="julho">07</option>
                        <option value="agosto">08</option>
                        <option value="setembro">09</option>
                        <option value="outubro">10</option>
                        <option value="novembro">11</option>
                        <option value="dezembro">12</option>
                    </select>

                    <select name="ano" required>
                        <option value="2021">21</option>
                        <option value="2022">22</option>
                        <option value="2023">23</option>
                        <option value="2024">24</option>
                        <option value="2025">25</option>
                        <option value="2026">26</option>
                        <option value="2027">27</option>
                        <option value="2028">28</option>
                        <option value="2029">29</option>
                        <option value="2030">30</option>
                        <option value="2031">31</option>
                        <option value="2032">32</option>
                        <option value="2033">33</option>
                        <option value="2034">34</option>
                        <option value="2035">35</option>

                    </select>

                </div>
```

gostaria da melhor solução pro meu problema, não precisa ser como eu to falando.

Comment: Benvindo ao StackOverflow em português! Coloque o que fez para auxiliar as pessoas em como direcionar a solução.

Comment: Importante sempre que postar uma pergunta explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e da **tentativa de solução**. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não é possível no `type=date`, no entanto existe o `<input type="month">`, só que o problema dele é que que apenas alguns navegadores o suportam e navegadores antigos (acaso precise de retrocompatibilidade) não irão suportar:

Confira o suporte no [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/mdn-html_elements_input_input-month), resumo dos navegadores com e sem suporte até o momento:

| Chrome | Edge | Firefox | Opera | Safari | WebView Android | Chrome Android | Firefox Android | Opera Android | Safari iOS | Samsung Internet |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 12 | [**não ***](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=888320) | 11 | [**não ***](https://webkit.org/b/200416) | sim | sim | 18 | sim | sim | sim |

Então no Firefox e Safari (dois navegadores muito usados), isso não vai funcionar.

Exemplo de uso:

```html
<input type="month">
```

O `type="month"` também suporta `min=""` e `max=""`, para definir a data mínima e máxima e para definir isso basta setar manualmente usando um valor vindo de um back-end ou via JavaScript, usando [`Element.setAttribute('')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) e use `Element.value=""` para setar o valor inicial ou o `<input ... value="">`, colocando entre as aspas o valor vindo do back-end.

Em JavaScript bastaria:

```
<input type="month" id="meucampo" max="2030-12">
<script>
var dataLocal = new Date;
var mes = dataLocal.getMonth() + 1;

//Se o mês for menor que 10 adiciona o 0 a frente
if (mes < 10) mes = "0" + mes;

var dataMinima = dataLocal.getFullYear() + "-" + ;
var meucampo = document.getElementById('meucampo');

meucampo.value = dataMinima;

// Data minima
meucampo.setAttribute("min", dataMinima);
</script>
```

Vela lembrar que isso é só exemplo.

Comment: a parte de aparecer só mês e ano deu certo.

Mas e para que o ano mínimo for o atual?

por exemplo, ta aparecendo pra selecionar ano infinito. e queria que o menor ano a aparecer seja 2022 ou mais precisamente o ano q o usuario está acessando o site.

Comment: @G'DogTrampos atualizei a resposta, demorei pq o site tinha ficado fora do ar.

Comment: qual seria a solução para que seja aceito em todos os navegadores?

Comment: @G'DogTrampos você pode fazer dois selects dinamicos ou usar uma biblioteca javascript que simule isso. Mas solução nativa não tem por enquanto, se tivesse pode ter certeza que eu teria postado :)

Comment: @G'DogTrampos Na [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/month#examples) tem um exemplo pra funcionar em qualquer browser (basicamente é o que já foi sugerido acima: dois selects, um pro mês, outro pro ano)

Comment: @hkotsubo eu tinha usado os dois selects mas quando eu fiz tive q fazer uma linha de codigo pra cada mês e uma linha pra cada ano. colocar 20 anos e 12 meses seria mt linha e muito trabalho.

Comment: @G'DogTrampos Leia o link que indiquei, veja que ele preenche os anos com JavaScript. E dá para adaptar e fazer o mesmo com meses (embora eu ache que 12 nem é tanto trabalho assim, mas enfim).

Answer (score -2):

HTML:

```
<input type="month">
```

JavaScript:

```
const anoAtual = new Date().getFullYear();
const mesAtual = new Date().getMonth();

const input = document.querySelector("input");

if(mesAtual <= 9) {
  input.setAttribute("min", `${anoAtual}-0${mesAtual + 1}`);
  input.setAttribute("value", `${anoAtual}-0${mesAtual + 1}`);
} else {
  input.setAttribute("min", `${anoAtual}-${mesAtual + 1}`);
  input.setAttribute("value", `${anoAtual}-${mesAtual + 1}`);
}
```

Estou adicionando o valor de 1 no `mesAtual` pois no JavaScript os meses são contados a partir do index 0. Criei um if e else para adicionar um 0 antes das unidades, pois esse é o padrão requerido pelo HTML, da para encurtar mais esse código porém dessa forma fica mais simples de ser entendido